# search data from elasticsearch with java native

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I want  retrieve  data  of document who have frameindex equal to 3 and  fcntup equal 29225 between tow date

[image: e]

But the result is

```
{"query":{"range":{"NewlnsServerTimestamp":{"from":"2017-11-14T00:00:00.000Z","to":"2017-11-14T13:27:42.000Z","include_lower":true,"include_upper":true,"boost":1.0}}}}
```

Is there  any solution to have and opertator between query ?

Comment: You need to add the range query as another must clause in the bool query if I understand you correctly

Comment: thanks it was helpful

Comment: No probs amigo!